# Android emulator crashes or startup

Tags: android, ubuntu, crash, emulation, stack-trace

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10 natively. I downloaded the android sdk and installed the oracle java 6 sdk (overwriting the openjdk I previously had). I created an emulator image for arm and one for x86. Then I ran the emulator from the command line.

The emulator crashes on startup. The verbose output is posted below. Anyone have ideas?

```
./emulator -verbose -avd ICS
emulator: found SDK root at /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux
emulator: Android virtual device file at: /.android/avd/ICS.ini
emulator: virtual device content at /.android/avd/ICS.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: /.android/avd/ICS.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: /.android/avd/ICS.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 16
emulator: found skin 'WVGA800' in directory: /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-16/skins
emulator: autoconfig: -skin WVGA800
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-16/skins
emulator: found skin-specific hardware.ini: /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-16/skins/WVGA800/hardware.ini
emulator: keyset loaded from: /.android/default.keyset
emulator: trying to load skin file '/workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/platforms/android-16/skins/WVGA800/layout'
emulator: skin network speed: 'full'
emulator: skin network delay: 'none'
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-16/x86//kernel-qemu
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-16/x86//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-16/x86//system.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data /.android/avd/ICS.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /.android/avd/ICS.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /.android/avd/ICS.avd/cache.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 512MB

Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = x86
  hw.ramSize = 512
  hw.screen = touch
  hw.mainKeys = yes
  hw.trackBall = yes
  hw.keyboard = no
  hw.keyboard.lid = no
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = yes
  hw.gsmModem = yes
  hw.gps = yes
  hw.battery = yes
  hw.accelerometer = yes
  hw.audioInput = yes
  hw.audioOutput = yes
  hw.sdCard = yes
  disk.cachePartition = yes
  disk.cachePartition.path = /.android/avd/ICS.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  hw.lcd.width = 480
  hw.lcd.height = 800
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 240
  hw.lcd.backlight = yes
  hw.gpu.enabled = no
  hw.camera.back = emulated
  hw.camera.front = none
  vm.heapSize = 48
  hw.sensors.proximity = yes
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = yes
  hw.sensors.orientation = yes
  hw.sensors.temperature = yes
  kernel.path = /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-16/x86//kernel-qemu
  kernel.parameters =  androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.checkjni=1
  disk.ramdisk.path = /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-16/x86//ramdisk.img

  disk.systemPartition.size = 255m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /.android/avd/ICS.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 200m
  avd.name = ICS
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "./emulator-x86"
emulator: argv[01] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[02] = "/.android/avd/ICS.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 ./emulator-x86 -android-hw /.android/avd/ICS.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: nand_add_dev: system,size=0xff00000,initfile=/workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/system-images/android-16/x86//system.img
emulator: mapping 'system' NAND image to /tmp/android-robert/emulator-htb5FB
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now ff1b000

emulator: nand_add_dev: userdata,size=0xc800000,file=/.android/avd/ICS.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: rounding devsize up to a full eraseunit, now c810000

emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '48m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '240'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '1'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'back'
emulator: nand_add_dev: cache,size=0x4200000,file=/.android/avd/ICS.avd/cache.img
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
emulator: No kvm device file detected
emulator: Kernel parameters: qemu.gles=0 qemu=1 console=ttyS0 android.qemud=ttyS1 androidboot.hardware=goldfish clocksource=pit android.checkjni=1 ndns=1
emulator:     trying to find: /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/tools/bios.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/pc-bios/bios.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/tools/vgabios-cirrus.bin

emulator:     trying to find: /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/pc-bios/vgabios-cirrus.bin

emulator: autoconfig: -scale 1
emulator: Could not open file: (null)/system/build.prop: No such file or directory
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
emulator: sent '0012host:emulator:5555' to ADB server
emulator: ping program: /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/tools/ddms
emulator: ping command: /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/tools/ddms ping emulator 20.0.3.0 "ATI Technologies Inc." "AMD Radeon HD 6700M Series" "4.2.11627 Compatibility Profile Context"
goldfish_fb_get_pixel_format:167: display surface,pixel format:
  bits/pixel:  16
  bytes/pixel: 2
  depth:       16
  red:         bits=5 mask=0xf800 shift=11 max=0x1f
  green:       bits=6 mask=0x7e0 shift=5 max=0x3f
  blue:        bits=5 mask=0x1f shift=0 max=0x1f
  alpha:       bits=0 mask=0x0 shift=0 max=0x0
### WARNING: could not find /etc/localtime or /usr/share/zoneinfo/localtime. unable to determine host timezone
*** glibc detected *** ./emulator-x86: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x0825c30a ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x73e42)[0x183e42]
/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x74525)[0x184525]
./emulator-x86[0x80e2702]
./emulator-x86[0x80e2a3c]
./emulator-x86[0x80fdf2b]
./emulator-x86[0x80fe059]
./emulator-x86[0x8101aa4]
./emulator-x86[0x8101d29]
./emulator-x86[0x80b8362]
./emulator-x86[0x80dd4cf]
./emulator-x86[0x80dd78f]
./emulator-x86[0x81347ba]
./emulator-x86[0x8134b5c]
./emulator-x86[0x815c79d]
[0xae5b9cbc]
======= Memory map: ========
00110000-002af000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 796184     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
002af000-002b1000 r--p 0019f000 08:07 796184     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
002b1000-002b2000 rw-p 001a1000 08:07 796184     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
002b2000-002b5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
002b5000-002d4000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1575117    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
002d4000-002d5000 r--p 0001f000 08:07 1575117    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
002d5000-002d6000 rw-p 00020000 08:07 1575117    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb.so.1.1.0
002d6000-002e6000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1580912    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
002e6000-002e7000 r--p 0000f000 08:07 1580912    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
002e7000-002e8000 rw-p 00010000 08:07 1580912    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXext.so.6.4.0
002e8000-002ef000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1578120    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
002ef000-002f0000 r--p 00006000 08:07 1578120    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
002f0000-002f1000 rw-p 00007000 08:07 1578120    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
002f1000-002f5000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1573672    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
002f5000-002f6000 r--p 00004000 08:07 1573672    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
002f6000-002f7000 rw-p 00005000 08:07 1573672    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
002f7000-00321000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 7097052    /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/libEGL_translator.so
00321000-00322000 rw-p 00029000 08:07 7097052    /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/libEGL_translator.so
00322000-00323000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00323000-0035e000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 7097020    /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/libGLES_CM_translator.so
0035e000-0035f000 rw-p 0003a000 08:07 7097020    /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/libGLES_CM_translator.so
0035f000-0039a000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1605324    /usr/lib/fglrx/libatiadlxx.so
0039a000-0039c000 rw-p 0003b000 08:07 1605324    /usr/lib/fglrx/libatiadlxx.so
0039c000-003ac000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
003ac000-003ae000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1578115    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
003ae000-003af000 r--p 00001000 08:07 1578115    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
003af000-003b0000 rw-p 00002000 08:07 1578115    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXinerama.so.1.0.0
003b0000-003b2000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1578101    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
003b2000-003b3000 r--p 00001000 08:07 1578101    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
003b3000-003b4000 rw-p 00002000 08:07 1578101    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdamage.so.1.1.0
003b4000-003b5000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1575985    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
003b5000-003b6000 r--p 00000000 08:07 1575985    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
003b6000-003b7000 rw-p 00001000 08:07 1575985    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11-xcb.so.1.0.0
003b7000-003cd000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1574695    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
003cd000-003ce000 r--p 00016000 08:07 1574695    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
003ce000-003cf000 rw-p 00017000 08:07 1574695    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxcb-glx.so.0.0.0
003d1000-003d8000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 800311     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
003d8000-003d9000 r--p 00006000 08:07 800311     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
003d9000-003da000 rw-p 00007000 08:07 800311     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
003da000-0042c000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1575416    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2
0042c000-0042e000 r--p 00051000 08:07 1575416    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2
0042e000-00433000 rwxp 00053000 08:07 1575416    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/mesa/libGL.so.1.2
00433000-00436000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1575929    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulse-simple.so.0.0.3
00436000-00437000 r--p 00002000 08:07 1575929    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulse-simple.so.0.0.3
00437000-00438000 rw-p 00003000 08:07 1575929    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulse-simple.so.0.0.3
00438000-00440000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 787446     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0.7.6
00440000-00441000 r--p 00007000 08:07 787446     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0.7.6
00441000-00442000 rw-p 00008000 08:07 787446     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libwrap.so.0.7.6
00442000-00448000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1578300    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0.7.1
00448000-00449000 r--p 00005000 08:07 1578300    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0.7.1
00449000-0044a000 rw-p 00006000 08:07 1578300    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libogg.so.0.7.1
0044a000-0045d000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 800295     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.15.so
0045d000-0045e000 ---p 00013000 08:07 800295     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.15.so
0045e000-0045f000 r--p 00013000 08:07 800295     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.15.so
0045f000-00460000 rw-p 00014000 08:07 800295     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libresolv-2.15.so
00460000-00462000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00468000-00473000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1573158    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0
00473000-00474000 r--p 0000a000 08:07 1573158    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0
00474000-00475000 rw-p 0000b000 08:07 1573158    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdrm.so.2.4.0
00475000-004c1000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1574348    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0.13.5
004c1000-004c2000 r--p 0004b000 08:07 1574348    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0.13.5
004c2000-004c3000 rw-p 0004c000 08:07 1574348    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulse.so.0.13.5
004cf000-004e6000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 800284     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
004e6000-004e7000 r--p 00016000 08:07 800284     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
004e7000-004e8000 rw-p 00017000 08:07 800284     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
004e8000-004ea000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
004ea000-0061a000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1578713    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
0061a000-0061b000 r--p 0012f000 08:07 1578713    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
0061b000-0061d000 rw-p 00130000 08:07 1578713    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6.3.0
0061d000-0061e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
0061e000-00681000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1575791    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulsecommon-1.1.so
00681000-00682000 r--p 00062000 08:07 1575791    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulsecommon-1.1.so
00682000-00683000 rw-p 00063000 08:07 1575791    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpulsecommon-1.1.so
00693000-0069b000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1574683    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
0069b000-0069c000 r--p 00007000 08:07 1574683    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
0069c000-0069d000 rw-p 00008000 08:07 1574683    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXrender.so.1.3.0
006b2000-006b6000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1575311    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
006b6000-006b7000 r--p 00003000 08:07 1575311    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
006b7000-006b8000 rw-p 00004000 08:07 1575311    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXxf86vm.so.1.0.0
006b8000-006ff000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 786514     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.5.8
006ff000-00700000 r--p 00046000 08:07 786514     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.5.8
00700000-00701000 rw-p 00047000 08:07 786514     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdbus-1.so.3.5.8
00701000-0074d000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1574947    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8.2.0
0074d000-0074e000 r--p 0004b000 08:07 1574947    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8.2.0
0074e000-0074f000 rw-p 0004c000 08:07 1574947    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libFLAC.so.8.2.0
00758000-0075a000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1574727    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
0075a000-0075b000 r--p 00001000 08:07 1574727    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
0075b000-0075c000 rw-p 00002000 08:07 1574727    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXau.so.6.0.0
0076a000-00771000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1605337    /usr/lib/fglrx/libatiuki.so.1.0
00771000-00772000 rw-p 00006000 08:07 1605337    /usr/lib/fglrx/libatiuki.so.1.0
0079b000-007a6000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 799916     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
007a6000-007a7000 r--p 0000a000 08:07 799916     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
007a7000-007a8000 rw-p 0000b000 08:07 799916     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
007a8000-00814000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1574961    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1.0.25
00814000-00815000 r--p 0006c000 08:07 1574961    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1.0.25
00815000-00816000 rw-p 0006d000 08:07 1574961    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libsndfile.so.1.0.25
00816000-0081a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
0081a000-00843000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1574959    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0.4.5
00843000-00844000 r--p 00028000 08:07 1574959    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0.4.5
00844000-00845000 rw-p 00029000 08:07 1574959    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbis.so.0.4.5
008cd000-008d3000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1578257    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjson.so.0.0.1
008d3000-008d4000 r--p 00005000 08:07 1578257    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjson.so.0.0.1
008d4000-008d5000 rw-p 00006000 08:07 1578257    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libjson.so.0.0.1
008e3000-008e6000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 799810     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
008e6000-008e7000 r--p 00002000 08:07 799810     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
008e7000-008e8000 rw-p 00003000 08:07 799810     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
00936000-0093b000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1578134    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0.3.1
0093b000-0093c000 r--p 00004000 08:07 1578134    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0.3.1
0093c000-0093d000 rw-p 00005000 08:07 1578134    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libasyncns.so.0.3.1
009c2000-009d1000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1573024    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0
009d1000-009d3000 r--p 0000f000 08:07 1573024    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0
009d3000-009d8000 rwxp 00011000 08:07 1573024    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libglapi.so.0.0.0
009d8000-009f8000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 786492     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
009f8000-009f9000 r--p 0001f000 08:07 786492     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
009f9000-009fa000 rw-p 00020000 08:07 786492     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
00a52000-00a8a000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 7097122    /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/libGLES_V2_translator.so
00a8a000-00a8b000 rw-p 00038000 08:07 7097122    /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/libGLES_V2_translator.so
00a8f000-00aab000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 787364     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
00aab000-00aac000 r--p 0001b000 08:07 787364     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
00aac000-00aad000 rw-p 0001c000 08:07 787364     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
00b44000-00b4d000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1578104    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
00b4d000-00b4e000 r--p 00008000 08:07 1578104    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
00b4e000-00b4f000 rw-p 00009000 08:07 1578104    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
00b63000-00b68000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1575107    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
00b68000-00b69000 r--p 00004000 08:07 1575107    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
00b69000-00b6a000 rw-p 00005000 08:07 1575107    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
00b6e000-00b98000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 799836     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
00b98000-00b99000 r--p 00029000 08:07 799836     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
00b99000-00b9a000 rw-p 0002a000 08:07 799836     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
00bb4000-00bf7000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 7097086    /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/libOpenglRender.so
00bf7000-00bfa000 rw-p 00043000 08:07 7097086    /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/tools/lib/libOpenglRender.so
00cc3000-00cc5000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 800571     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libutil-2.15.so
00cc5000-00cc6000 r--p 00001000 08:07 800571     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libutil-2.15.so
00cc6000-00cc7000 rw-p 00002000 08:07 800571     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libutil-2.15.so
00d16000-00de2000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1605343    /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so.1.2
00de2000-00dee000 rwxp 000cb000 08:07 1605343    /usr/lib/fglrx/libGL.so.1.2
00dee000-00e03000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
00e11000-00ee9000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1577340    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
00ee9000-00eea000 ---p 000d8000 08:07 1577340    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
00eea000-00eee000 r--p 000d8000 08:07 1577340    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
00eee000-00eef000 rw-p 000dc000 08:07 1577340    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
00eef000-00ef6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00f1c000-00f32000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 799861     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.15.so
00f32000-00f33000 r--p 00015000 08:07 799861     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.15.so
00f33000-00f34000 rw-p 00016000 08:07 799861     /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.15.so
00f34000-00f36000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
00f5b000-00f5c000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0          [vdso]
00f5c000-032d4000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1605327    /usr/lib/fglrx/dri/fglrx_dri.so
032d4000-033c5000 rw-p 02378000 08:07 1605327    /usr/lib/fglrx/dri/fglrx_dri.so
033c5000-03493000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
03493000-035f9000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 1574949    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2.0.8
035f9000-0360a000 r--p 00165000 08:07 1574949    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2.0.8
0360a000-0360b000 rw-p 00176000 08:07 1574949    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libvorbisenc.so.2.0.8
08048000-082d6000 r-xp 00000000 08:07 6842098    /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator-x86
082d6000-082da000 rw-p 0028e000 08:07 6842098    /workspace/android/packages/android-sdk-linux/tools/emulator-x86
082da000-084cf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
084cf000-084d1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
084d1000-0850f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
09ad0000-0a390000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0          [heap]
79ce5000-7dce6000 r--s 00000000 00:12 22073      /run/shm/pulse-shm-2201308209
7dce6000-7dfff000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 23265286   /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
7dfff000-7e000000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7e000000-7e800000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7e800000-7e821000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7e821000-7e900000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7e9b9000-7e9ba000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
7e9ba000-7f1ba000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
7f1ba000-831bb000 rw-s 00000000 00:12 320015     /run/shm/pulse-shm-3217607746
831bb000-831bc000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
831bc000-839bc000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
839bc000-839c3000 r--s 00000000 08:07 1599665    /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
839c3000-879c4000 rw-s 00000000 00:12 320824     /run/shm/pulse-shm-3368864694Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: I've got this exact same problem

Comment: Hello take a look here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850006/has-anyone-seen-or-know-the-cause-of-this-error-message-the-android-emulator-wi

Comment: You're right this fixed my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks jose-rodrigues

Link to answer that fixed my problem:

[Has anyone seen or know the cause of this error message? The Android emulator will not start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850006/has-anyone-seen-or-know-the-cause-of-this-error-message-the-android-emulator-wi)