# Has anyone seen or know the cause of this error message? The Android emulator will not start

Tags: android

When I try to launch an AVD -any- AVD the emulator spits out this error and a huge backtrace:

```
*** glibc detected *** /opt/android-sdk/tools/emulator-arm: munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer: 0x082550ca ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/usr/lib32/libc.so.6(+0x75922)[0xf748a922]
/usr/lib32/libc.so.6(+0x75fe5)[0xf748afe5]
/opt/android-sdk/tools/emulator-arm[0x80df9d2]
/opt/android-sdk/tools/emulator-arm[0x80dfd0c]
/opt/android-sdk/tools/emulator-arm[0x80fb1fb]
/opt/android-sdk/tools/emulator-arm[0x80fb329]
/opt/android-sdk/tools/emulator-arm[0x80fed74]
/opt/android-sdk/tools/emulator-arm[0x80feff9]
/opt/android-sdk/tools/emulator-arm[0x80b5632]
/opt/android-sdk/tools/emulator-arm[0x80da79f]
/opt/android-sdk/tools/emulator-arm[0x80daa5f]
/opt/android-sdk/tools/emulator-arm[0x8131cb3]
/opt/android-sdk/tools/emulator-arm[0x813234f]
/opt/android-sdk/tools/emulator-arm[0x814402d]
[0xebeee67d]
======= Memory map: ========
08048000-082d8000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2896026                            /opt/android-sdk/tools/emulator-arm
082d8000-082dc000 rw-p 0028f000 08:01 2896026                            /opt/android-sdk/tools/emulator-arm
082dc000-084d6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
084d6000-084d7000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
084d7000-08514000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
095b0000-09dc1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
b7be4000-b7be5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
b7be5000-b7efe000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 914358272                          /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
b7efe000-bbeff000 r--s 00000000 00:0f 8877                               /dev/shm/pulse-shm-3330042333
bbeff000-bbf00000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
bbf00000-bc700000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:17238]
bc700000-bc721000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
bc721000-bc800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
bc80a000-bc80b000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
bc80b000-bd00b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:17237]
bd00b000-c100c000 rw-s 00000000 00:0f 619464                             /dev/shm/pulse-shm-4256856931
c100c000-c100d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
c100d000-c180d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:17236]
c180d000-c580e000 rw-s 00000000 00:0f 620934                             /dev/shm/pulse-shm-22245207
c580e000-c5973000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1844920                            /usr/lib32/libvorbisenc.so.2.0.9
c5973000-c5984000 r--p 00165000 08:01 1844920                            /usr/lib32/libvorbisenc.so.2.0.9
c5984000-c5985000 rw-p 00176000 08:01 1844920                            /usr/lib32/libvorbisenc.so.2.0.9
c5afd000-eb700000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
eb700000-f3700000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
f3700000-f3721000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f3721000-f3800000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
f3819000-f382c000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1842908                            /usr/lib32/libresolv-2.16.so
f382c000-f382d000 ---p 00013000 08:01 1842908                            /usr/lib32/libresolv-2.16.so
f382d000-f382e000 r--p 00013000 08:01 1842908                            /usr/lib32/libresolv-2.16.so
f382e000-f382f000 rw-p 00014000 08:01 1842908                            /usr/lib32/libresolv-2.16.so
f382f000-f3831000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f3831000-f3846000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1842907                            /usr/lib32/libnsl-2.16.so
f3846000-f3847000 r--p 00014000 08:01 1842907                            /usr/lib32/libnsl-2.16.so
f3847000-f3848000 rw-p 00015000 08:01 1842907                            /usr/lib32/libnsl-2.16.so
f3848000-f384a000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f384a000-f3850000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1844902                            /usr/lib32/libogg.so.0.8.0
f3850000-f3851000 r--p 00005000 08:01 1844902                            /usr/lib32/libogg.so.0.8.0
f3851000-f3852000 rw-p 00006000 08:01 1844902                            /usr/lib32/libogg.so.0.8.0
f3852000-f387d000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1844915                            /usr/lib32/libvorbis.so.0.4.6
f387d000-f387e000 r--p 0002a000 08:01 1844915                            /usr/lib32/libvorbis.so.0.4.6
f387e000-f387f000 rw-p 0002b000 08:01 1844915                            /usr/lib32/libvorbis.so.0.4.6
f387f000-f38ce000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1844912                            /usr/lib32/libFLAC.so.8.2.0
f38ce000-f38cf000 ---p 0004f000 08:01 1844912                            /usr/lib32/libFLAC.so.8.2.0
f38cf000-f38d0000 r--p 0004f000 08:01 1844912                            /usr/lib32/libFLAC.so.8.2.0
f38d0000-f38d1000 rw-p 00050000 08:01 1844912                            /usr/lib32/libFLAC.so.8.2.0
f38d1000-f38d2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0 
f38d2000-f40d2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [stack:17235]
f40d2000-f413f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1844928                            /usr/lib32/libsndfile.so.1.0.25
f413f000-f4141000 r--p 0006c000 08:01 1844928                            /usr/lib32/libsndfile.so.1.0.25
f4141000-f4142000 rw-p 0006e000 08:01 1844928                            /usr/lib32/libsndfile.so.1.0.25
f4142000-f4146000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f4146000-f418f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1844877                            /usr/lib32/libdbus-1.so.3.7.2
f418f000-f4190000 r--p 00048000 08:01 1844877                            /usr/lib32/libdbus-1.so.3.7.2
f4190000-f4191000 rw-p 00049000 08:01 1844877                            /usr/lib32/libdbus-1.so.3.7.2
f4191000-f41f5000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1844945                            /usr/lib32/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-2.1.so
f41f5000-f41f6000 r--p 00064000 08:01 1844945                            /usr/lib32/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-2.1.so
f41f6000-f41f7000 rw-p 00065000 08:01 1844945                            /usr/lib32/pulseaudio/libpulsecommon-2.1.so
f41f7000-f43f7000 rw-s 8688d000 00:05 12939                              /dev/nvidia0
f43f9000-f45f9000 rw-s 1b1954000 00:05 12939                             /dev/nvidia0
f45f9000-f47f9000 rw-s 1ce2ce000 00:05 12939                             /dev/nvidia0
f47f9000-f48f9000 rw-s 15d57b000 00:05 12939                             /dev/nvidia0
f48f9000-f48fd000 rw-s 2127c5000 00:05 12939                             /dev/nvidia0
f48fd000-f491d000 rw-s c80e0000 00:05 12939                              /dev/nvidia0
f491d000-f491e000 rw-s cfeed000 00:05 12939                              /dev/nvidia0
f491e000-f495e000 rw-s 1fe97a000 00:05 12939                             /dev/nvidia0
f495e000-f497e000 rw-s 1b1a26000 00:05 12939                             /dev/nvidia0
f497e000-f49be000 rw-s 203bb5000 00:05 12939                             /dev/nvidia0
f49be000-f49de000 rw-s 209291000 00:05 12939                             /dev/nvidia0
f49de000-f49df000 rw-s cfeeb000 00:05 12939                              /dev/nvidia0
f49df000-f4a1f000 rw-s 1a6d61000 00:05 12939                             /dev/nvidia0
f4a1f000-f4a3f000 rw-s 199d13000 00:05 12939                             /dev/nvidia0
f4a3f000-f4ad5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f4adc000-f4ae1000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1844889                            /usr/lib32/libasyncns.so.0.3.1
f4ae1000-f4ae2000 r--p 00004000 08:01 1844889                            /usr/lib32/libasyncns.so.0.3.1
f4ae2000-f4ae3000 rw-p 00005000 08:01 1844889                            /usr/lib32/libasyncns.so.0.3.1
f4ae3000-f4aea000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1844882                            /usr/lib32/libjson.so.0.0.1
f4aea000-f4aeb000 r--p 00006000 08:01 1844882                            /usr/lib32/libjson.so.0.0.1
f4aeb000-f4aec000 rw-p 00007000 08:01 1844882                            /usr/lib32/libjson.so.0.0.1
f4aec000-f4b39000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1844939                            /usr/lib32/libpulse.so.0.14.3
f4b39000-f4b3a000 ---p 0004d000 08:01 1844939                            /usr/lib32/libpulse.so.0.14.3
f4b3a000-f4b3b000 r--p 0004d000 08:01 1844939                            /usr/lib32/libpulse.so.0.14.3
f4b3b000-f4b3c000 rw-p 0004e000 08:01 1844939                            /usr/lib32/libpulse.so.0.14.3
f4b3c000-f4b3f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1844940                            /usr/lib32/libpulse-simple.so.0.0.3
f4b3f000-f4b40000 r--p 00002000 08:01 1844940                            /usr/lib32/libpulse-simple.so.0.0.3
f4b40000-f4b41000 rw-p 00003000 08:01 1844940                            /usr/lib32/libpulse-simple.so.0.0.3
f4b41000-f4bc2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f4bc2000-f4bcd000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1842901                            /usr/lib32/libnss_files-2.16.so
f4bcd000-f4bce000 r--p 0000a000 08:01 1842901                            /usr/lib32/libnss_files-2.16.so
f4bce000-f4bcf000 rw-p 0000b000 08:01 1842901                            /usr/lib32/libnss_files-2.16.so
f4bf6000-f4c77000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f4c77000-f4caf000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2896245                            /opt/android-sdk/tools/lib/libGLES_V2_translator.so
f4caf000-f4cb0000 rw-p 00038000 08:01 2896245                            /opt/android-sdk/tools/lib/libGLES_V2_translator.so
f4cb0000-f4ceb000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2896244                            /opt/android-sdk/tools/lib/libGLES_CM_translator.so
f4ceb000-f4cec000 rw-p 0003a000 08:01 2896244                            /opt/android-sdk/tools/lib/libGLES_CM_translator.so
f4cec000-f4cf4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f4cf4000-f6981000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1843359                            /usr/lib32/libnvidia-glcore.so.304.51
f6981000-f69e6000 rwxp 01c8d000 08:01 1843359                            /usr/lib32/libnvidia-glcore.so.304.51
f69e6000-f69f9000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
f69f9000-f69fc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1843357                            /usr/lib32/libnvidia-tls.so.304.51
f69fc000-f69fd000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 1843357                            /usr/lib32/libnvidia-tls.so.304.51
f69fd000-f6aaa000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1843355                            /usr/lib32/libGL.so.304.51
f6aaa000-f6aca000 rwxp 000ac000 08:01 1843355                            /usr/lib32/libGL.so.304.51
f6aca000-f6ad9000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
f6ada000-f6adb000 rw-s 2127c4000 00:05 12939                             /dev/nvidia0
f6adb000-f6adf000 rw-s 209326000 00:05 12939                             /dev/nvidia0
f6adf000-f6ae0000 rw-s da641000 00:05 12939                              /dev/nvidia0
f6ae0000-f6ae1000 rw-s 1c4a0c000 00:05 12939                             /dev/nvidia0
f6ae1000-f6ae2000 rw-s 2125bf000 00:05 12939                             /dev/nvidia0
f6ae3000-f6b00000 rw-s 233b59000 00:05 12939                             /dev/nvidia0
f6b00000-f6b2a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2896247                            /opt/android-sdk/tools/lib/libEGL_translator.so
f6b2a000-f6b2b000 rw-p 00029000 08:01 2896247                            /opt/android-sdk/tools/lib/libEGL_translator.so
f6b2b000-f6b2c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f6b2c000-f6b6f000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 2896246                            /opt/android-sdk/tools/lib/libOpenglRender.so
f6b6f000-f6b72000 rw-p 00043000 08:01 2896246                            /opt/android-sdk/tools/lib/libOpenglRender.so
f6b72000-f7276000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f7276000-f727a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1843309                            /usr/lib32/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
f727a000-f727b000 r--p 00003000 08:01 1843309                            /usr/lib32/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
f727b000-f727c000 rw-p 00004000 08:01 1843309                            /usr/lib32/libXfixes.so.3.1.0
f727c000-f7285000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1843427                            /usr/lib32/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
f7285000-f7286000 r--p 00008000 08:01 1843427                            /usr/lib32/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
f7286000-f7287000 rw-p 00009000 08:01 1843427                            /usr/lib32/libXcursor.so.1.0.2
f7287000-f7290000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1843433                            /usr/lib32/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
f7290000-f7291000 r--p 00008000 08:01 1843433                            /usr/lib32/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
f7291000-f7292000 rw-p 00009000 08:01 1843433                            /usr/lib32/libXrandr.so.2.2.0
f7292000-f729a000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1843424                            /usr/lib32/libXrender.so.1.3.0
f729a000-f729b000 r--p 00007000 08:01 1843424                            /usr/lib32/libXrender.so.1.3.0
f729b000-f729c000 rw-p 00008000 08:01 1843424                            /usr/lib32/libXrender.so.1.3.0
f729c000-f72ac000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1843342                            /usr/lib32/libXext.so.6.4.0
f72ac000-f72ad000 r--p 0000f000 08:01 1843342                            /usr/lib32/libXext.so.6.4.0
f72ad000-f72ae000 rw-p 00010000 08:01 1843342                            /usr/lib32/libXext.so.6.4.0
f72ae000-f72b3000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1843198                            /usr/lib32/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
f72b3000-f72b4000 r--p 00004000 08:01 1843198                            /usr/lib32/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
f72b4000-f72b5000 rw-p 00005000 08:01 1843198                            /usr/lib32/libXdmcp.so.6.0.0
f72b5000-f72b7000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1843202                            /usr/lib32/libXau.so.6.0.0
f72b7000-f72b8000 r--p 00001000 08:01 1843202                            /usr/lib32/libXau.so.6.0.0
f72b8000-f72b9000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 1843202                            /usr/lib32/libXau.so.6.0.0
f72b9000-f72d9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1843251                            /usr/lib32/libxcb.so.1.1.0
f72d9000-f72da000 r--p 0001f000 08:01 1843251                            /usr/lib32/libxcb.so.1.1.0
f72da000-f72db000 rw-p 00020000 08:01 1843251                            /usr/lib32/libxcb.so.1.1.0
f72db000-f740e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1843302                            /usr/lib32/libX11.so.6.3.0
f740e000-f740f000 r--p 00132000 08:01 1843302                            /usr/lib32/libX11.so.6.3.0
f740f000-f7412000 rw-p 00133000 08:01 1843302                            /usr/lib32/libX11.so.6.3.0
f7412000-f7415000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f7415000-f75b9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1842853                            /usr/lib32/libc-2.16.so
f75b9000-f75bb000 r--p 001a4000 08:01 1842853                            /usr/lib32/libc-2.16.so
f75bb000-f75bc000 rw-p 001a6000 08:01 1842853                            /usr/lib32/libc-2.16.so
f75bc000-f75bf000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f75bf000-f75d9000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1843408                            /usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1
f75d9000-f75da000 rw-p 00019000 08:01 1843408                            /usr/lib32/libgcc_s.so.1
f75da000-f75dc000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1842910                            /usr/lib32/libutil-2.16.so
f75dc000-f75dd000 r--p 00001000 08:01 1842910                            /usr/lib32/libutil-2.16.so
f75dd000-f75de000 rw-p 00002000 08:01 1842910                            /usr/lib32/libutil-2.16.so
f75de000-f761b000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1842906                            /usr/lib32/libm-2.16.so
f761b000-f761c000 r--p 0003d000 08:01 1842906                            /usr/lib32/libm-2.16.so
f761c000-f761d000 rw-p 0003e000 08:01 1842906                            /usr/lib32/libm-2.16.so
f761d000-f761e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f761e000-f76fa000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1843412                            /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
f76fa000-f76fb000 ---p 000dc000 08:01 1843412                            /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
f76fb000-f76ff000 r--p 000dc000 08:01 1843412                            /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
f76ff000-f7700000 rw-p 000e0000 08:01 1843412                            /usr/lib32/libstdc++.so.6.0.17
f7700000-f7707000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
f7707000-f770e000 r-xp 00000000 08:01 1842909                            /usr/lib32/librt-2.16.so
```

I can't find anyone else who has this problem, and I have no idea what's causing it.

Answer (score 7):

It probably comes from the fact that you don't have a localtime file (I got the same problem)

To fix it you need to create it:

```
ln -sf /usr/share/zoneinfo/US/Eastern /etc/localtime
```

I hope it will help you

Comment: I have the same issue and this didn't resolve it :(
A "cat /etc/timezone" shows the linked file so the symbolic link works?